# Does the Kaundinyasa/Kaundinya Gotra derive it's lineage from Buddha's disciple Kodanna?

Tags: rishi, gotra, ancestry

I have been trying to trace the history of the Kaundinyasa gotra. Most of the references I find imply that Kaundinya was a brahmin at the court of the father of prince Siddharth (later Gautam Buddha) and was the only one to predict the princes impending Buddhahood. Later he became one of the closest members of Buddha's immediate group of monks. 
However I also find a few references (unverified) to Kaundinya(s) in other contexts, [some dating back to Yudhishthira's court](http://www.brahminpedia.com/2016/03/kaundinya-gotra-origin-and-history.html).
Does anyone have any specific information references on the individual credited with originating the gotra by the same name?

Comment: there is a saying 'rishi-moolam, nadi-moolam thedaadhe' - don't search for origin of rishi & river (it's very hard to find). But, keep in mind, there could be many common people with same name as rishis, doesn't mean they are gotra-pravartaka. Only rishis (with great penance) have gotras named after them